# What is the contradiction in the proof of the halting theorem?

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

[image]

In the standard proof of the halting theorem, you are asked to assume that a TM_0() exists that takes another TM_1() and a string W and outputs whether TM_1() halts or executes forever right on string W, right? The proof seems to be to assume that such a TM_0() exists. Now a new TM_2() is taken that takes TM_0() as input as halts if TM_0() executes forever, and executes forever if it halts. Now from what I understand such a TM_2() is supposed to mean a contradiction, which in turn implies that TM_(0) is a contradiction. I have trouble understanding how this step in TM_2() constitutes a contradiction. All these steps seem reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1):

You actually have a missing detail on how the machine $TM_2$ is defined (and a bit of confusion between $TM_1$ and $TM_0$). Let's clear this up. You start by the assumption that there is a machine $TM_0$ that operates as follows. On input $x = <TM_1, w>$, the machine $TM_0$ answers "yes" whenever $TM_1$ halts on its input $w$, and $TM_0$ answers "no" whenever $TM_1$ does not halt on its input $w$.

Now we define a machine $TM_2$. On input $z = <TM_1>$ which a description of a machine, denoted $TM_1$, the machine $TM_2$ runs $TM_0$ on $x = <TM_1, TM_1>$ and returns the opposite answer of $TM_0$. In words, **the machine $TM_2$ answers "no" when $TM_1$ halts on itself, and answers "yes" when $TM_1$ does not halt on itself.**

To get a contradiction, consider what happens when we feed $TM_2$ to itself as an input. That is, consider the case where the input of $TM_2$ is $z = <TM_2>$. One of the following holds:

1. $TM_2(TM_2)$ = "yes", and so in this case $TM_0(<TM_2, TM_2>)$ = "no". Hence, by the definition of $TM_0$, $TM_2$ does not halt on itself.
2. $TM_2(TM_2)$ = "no", and so in this case $TM_0(<TM_2, TM_2>)$ = "yes". Hence, by the definition of $TM_0$, $TM_2$ halts on itself.

All in all, we have that by the two items above that $TM_2(TM_2)$ = "yes" iff $TM_2$ halts on itself, which is clearly a contradiction to $TM_2$'s definition (see the bolded sentence above).